# Error with xassoccnt package

Tags: counters, xassoccnt

I have a document in two parts (which is a model that I need many times), each part starting with page number 1. I must then write the total number of pages of the whole document. I use the package xassoccnt for this purpose. But my document has 4 pages, and the command \TotalValue{totalpages} gives 7 pages (see lines 108 and 171 of my code below)!
Can someone have a solution to this error?
Thanks a lot!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,textsf]{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                                    READ ME FIRST                                     %
%                                    *************                                     %
%                                                                                      %
%    !!!!! This file has to be runned twice for the command \N to be defined !!!!!     %
%                                                                                      %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Préambule
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%BEGIN_FOLD % Packages % Filigrane % Mise en page et en-tête % Macros personnelles
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Packages
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Pour le français
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

% Pour les en-têtes et la mise en page
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace} %pour \begin{spacing}{...} \end{spacing}
% Pour le nombre total de pages
\usepackage{xassoccnt} % commande \TotalValue{totalpages} (nouveau compteur déclaré à la ligne suivante: `totalpages`)
\DeclareTotalAssociatedCounters{page}{totalpages}
% Pour les énumérations, les citations, les graphiques
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumerate}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Mise en page et en-tête
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Dimensions du texte
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{3cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{0.5cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-2.5cm}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-1.2cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{59.51pt}% hauteur de l'en-tête
\setlength{\headsep}{30pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{50pt}


\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.pt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Macros personnelles
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%




%END_FOLD
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Commandes de titre (À ADAPTER)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\author{Robin Pereboom}
\newcommand{\session}{mars 20XX}
\newcommand{\DureePartOne}{XX minutes}
\newcommand{\DureePartTwo}{XX minutes}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Début du document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    \begin{spacing}{1.5}
        
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % Corps du document
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % PREMIÈRE PARTIE - BEGIN
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %BEGIN_FOLD % Page de garde première partie % Tableau dynamique
        \cfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPagePart01}}%page X/Y %pied de page centre
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % Page de garde première partie
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        ~
        \vspace{1.\baselineskip}
        \begin{center}
            {\LARGE \textbf{Examen d'admission: session \session}}\\
            {\Large École de commerce de Fribourg et Bulle\\
                École de culture générale de Fribourg et Bulle}\\
            \vspace{2.\baselineskip}
            \uppercase{\textbf{\huge Mathématiques}}\\
            {\textbf{\LARGE Première partie, sans calculatrice}}\\
            \vspace{2.\baselineskip}
            \framebox[\textwidth][l]{
                \begin{tabular}{ll}
                    Durée de l'épreuve: &première partie: \DureePartOne\\
                    &seconde partie: \DureePartTwo\\
                    &total: 60 minutes\\
                    \\
                    Ouvrages et matériel autorisés: &\parbox[t]{9cm}{règle graduée, compas et rapporteur}\\
                    \\
                    Barème: & 50 points au total\\
                    \\
                    Nombres de pages incluant celle-ci: &première partie: \pageref{LastPagePart01} pages\\
                    & seconde partie: \pageref{LastPagePart02} pages\\
                    & total: \TotalValue{totalpages} pages\\
                \end{tabular}
            }
            
        \end{center}
    
        %***********************************************
        \newpage
        
        \part*{\LARGE{Première partie, sans calculatrice}}
        \emph{\Large{Durée: \DureePartOne.}}
        %END_FOLD
        
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % Corps de l'examen - première partie (À ADAPTER)
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        
        \section{Exercice}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item
            \item
        \end{enumerate}
        
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % PREMIÈRE PARTIE - END
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \label{LastPagePart01}
        
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % SECONDE PARTIE - BEGIN
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %BEGIN_FOLD % Page de garde seconde partie
        \newpage
        \cfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPagePart02}}%page X/Y %pied de page centre
        
        %the two following lines are needed, instead of only `\setcounter{page}{1}`, for the counter `totalpages` to be at the correct number of pages (and the `page` counter to be reset to the value one at the beginning of the second part)
        \setcounter{page}{0}
        \stepcounter{page} .
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % Page de garde seconde partie
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        ~
        \vspace{1.\baselineskip}
        \begin{center}
            {\LARGE \textbf{Examen d'admission: session \session}}\\
            {\Large École de commerce de Fribourg et Bulle\\
                École de culture générale de Fribourg et Bulle}\\
            \vspace{2.\baselineskip}
            \uppercase{\textbf{\huge Mathématiques}}\\
            {\textbf{\LARGE Seconde partie, avec calculatrice}}\\
            \vspace{2.\baselineskip}
            \framebox[\textwidth][l]{
                \begin{tabular}{ll}
                    Durée de l'épreuve: &première partie: \DureePartOne\\
                    &seconde partie: \DureePartTwo\\
                    &total: 60 minutes\\
                    \\
                    Ouvrages et matériel autorisés: &\parbox[t]{9cm}{machine à calculer (calculatrice autorisée : Casio fx-85, TI-30 (mais non TI-30X PRO) ou modèle équivalent; en aucun cas une calculatrice graphique, programmable ou permettant de résoudre des équations ne sera autorisée), règle graduée, compas et rapporteur}\\
                    \\
                    Barème: & 50 points au total\\
                    \\
                    Nombres de pages incluant celle-ci: &première partie: \pageref{LastPagePart01} pages\\
                    & seconde partie: \pageref{LastPagePart02} pages\\
                    & total: \TotalValue{totalpages} pages\\
                \end{tabular}
            }
            
        \end{center}
        
        \newpage
        
        \part*{\LARGE{Seconde partie, avec calculatrice}}
        \emph{\Large{Durée: \DureePartTwo.}}
        \emph{\textbf {\Large Attention! \large Pour toute cette seconde partie, calculer le plus précisément possible; arrondir ensuite chaque réponse finale au centième.}}
        %END_FOLD
        
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % Corps de l'examen - seconde partie (À ADAPTER)
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        
        \section{Exercice}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item
            \item
        \end{enumerate}
    
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % SECONDE PARTIE _ END
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

        \label{LastPagePart02}
    \end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: don't use the name `totalpages`, that counter is already defined in latex. Use e.g. `\DeclareTotalAssociatedCounters{page}{TOTALPAGES}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!